# Do equivariant morphisms induce representable maps of quotient stacks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, equivariant

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a $G$-equivariant map between schemes $X$, $Y$ with action of a flat group scheme $G$. Then why is the induced map of algebraic stacks $[X/G] \to [Y/G]$ representable?

Answer (score 6):

Because

first, $Y\to [Y/G]$ is a chart

second, the following diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y \\
@VVV @VVV \\
[X/G] @>>> [Y/G]
\end{CD}
$$
is cartesian (this is so because any morphism between two $G$-torsors is an isomorphism).